# MongoDB - How to use $graphLookup then $group and $sort after

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have this dataset:

```json
    [
        {
            _id: '1',
            name: 'test1',
            children: ['test2', so on...],
            status: 'enabled',
            version: 1,
        },
        {
            _id: '2',
            name: 'test2',
            children: [],
            status: 'enabled',
            version: 1,
        },
        {
            _id: '3',
            name: 'test2',
            children: ['test3'],
            status: 'enabled',
            version: 2,
        },
        {
            _id: '4',
            name: 'test2',
            children: [],
            status: 'disabled',
            version: 3,
        },
        {
            _id: '5',
            name: 'test3',
            children: [],
            status: 'enabled',
            version: 1,
        }
    ]
```

What I need to do is to get the children of `_id=1` item and return the enabled ones and highest version.

Is there a way for me to do it plainly via aggregation stages or do I have to do it manually by code?

Current aggregation query that I have:

```js
    db.Collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { name: 'test1', status: 'enabled' }
        },
        {
            $graphLookup: {
                from: "Collection",
                startWith: "$children",
                connectFromField: "children",
                connectToField: "name",
                as: "spreadChildren",
                restrictSearchWithMatch: {
                    status: 'enabled'
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

This is the expected result:

```json
    [
      {
        name: 'test1',
        children: ['test2'],
        status: 'enabled',
        version: 1,
        spreadChildren: [
          {
            _id: '3',
            name: 'test2',
            children: [],
            status: 'enabled',
            version: 2,
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you give an example to illustrate why `$graphLookup` is needed? For now, I think a `$lookup` will be good enough as you just need 1 level traversal.

Comment: No, graphlookup works as it outputs [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GJXcYEnFKl8), you have to complete a graph

Comment: @ray I think $lookup is only used for joining different collections. Also I used $graphLookup to recursively look for children of different nodes

Comment: `$lookup` can perform self lookup too. Can you update your example that you have more than 1 layer of children so we can verify whether the recursion works if we have some solution.

Comment: @ray oh I didn't know that $lookup can do that, thanks! I have now updated the example test data hoping you could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the followings in aggregation pipeline:

1. `$unwind` the the `$graphLookup` result.
2. `$sort` by `version`
3. `$group` at `spreadChildren.name` level and persist all fields; use `$first` to keep the largest `version` element
4. `$group` again on `_id` level to revert back to expected output

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "test1",
      status: "enabled"
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$children",
      connectFromField: "children",
      connectToField: "name",
      as: "spreadChildren",
      restrictSearchWithMatch: {
        status: "enabled"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$spreadChildren"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "spreadChildren.version": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        name: "$spreadChildren.name"
      },
      children: {
        $first: "$children"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      spreadChildren: {
        $first: "$spreadChildren"
      },
      status: {
        $first: "$status"
      },
      version: {
        $first: "$version"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      children: {
        $first: "$children"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      spreadChildren: {
        $push: "$spreadChildren"
      },
      status: {
        $first: "$status"
      },
      version: {
        $first: "$version"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hH833WqncwC) for your reference.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I'll try to read more on that $unwind and $first as I'm not familiar with those. This really helps. Thanks!